# Is there a way to clear the Navigation Service or not register a frame?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I'm developing an aplication for Windows 7, and I need to block a page.. my solutions are not register that frame or clear all the frames in back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing that you mean you have a page on the Back-stack that you want to remove --

In the new Mango SDK, there's a Method you can try [NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry.aspx)

However it might be easier to just use a boolean and check in `OnNavigatedTo`:

At page where you need to go back > 1 pages:

in `App.xaml.cs:`

```
public static bool IsBackwardNavigation = false;
public static string PageContext = string.Empty;
```

`Page2.xaml.cs` :

```
public void YourFunction()
{
App.PageContext = "MainPage";
App.IsBackwardNavigation = true;

if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
   NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

And in each page's `OnNavigatedTo`:

```
Page1.xaml.cs:
    string Page1 = "Page1";

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
           if (App.IsBackwardNavigation)
    {

    if (!Page1.Equals(App.NavigationContext)
        {
//since this page's name is not the correct page, the page will go back again.
        if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
           NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
        else
        {
//this is the page we're trying to get to
        App.IsBackwardNavigation = false;
        App.NavigationContext = string.Empty;


        }

    } 
        }
    }
```